# Linux cgroups: limit CPU usage in absolute values which do not depend on CPU speed

Tags: linux, cpu, limit, cgroups, quota

I have a server with a 2.4GHz processor. And there are several cgroups, each one allowed to use 25% of CPU. That's equal to 600MHz.

Then I replace the CPU with a faster one, let's say 3.0GHz. If I use `cpu.shares`, my containers will continue to get 25% of 3.0GHz which is now equal to 750MHz.

That means that after CPU replacement I have to reconfigure my cgroups to make them consume not more than 20% of CPU.

Is there a way to avoid this trouble during a CPU upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

Shares are relative among groups. For example, assigning 25% of CPU means that a cgroup will observe "at least" that much of CPU, but it can use more. From the [red hat docs on cgroups](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu.html):

> Note that shares of CPU time are distributed per all CPU cores on multi-core systems. Even if a cgroup is limited to less than 100% of CPU on a multi-core system, it may use 100% of each individual CPU core.
>
> ...
>
> The actual amount of CPU time that is available to a cgroup can vary depending on the number of cgroups that exist on the system. If a cgroup has a relative share of 1000 and two other cgroups have a relative share of 500, the first cgroup receives 50% of all CPU time in cases when processes in all cgroups attempt to use 100% of the CPU. However, if another cgroup is added with a relative share of 1000, the first cgroup is only allowed 33% of the CPU (the rest of the cgroups receive 16.5%, 16.5%, and 33% of CPU).

If you want a hard limit on CPU bandwidth, you can use `cpu.cfs_quota_us` and `cpu.cfs_period_us`. From the [Kernel's CFS docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt):

> The bandwidth allowed for a group is specified using a quota and period. Within each given "period" (microseconds), a group is allowed to consume only up to "quota" microseconds of CPU time. When the CPU bandwidth consumption of a
> group exceeds this limit (for that period), the tasks belonging to its hierarchy will be throttled and are not allowed to run again until the next
> period.

However, neither of these two options will allow you to port a group between distinct CPUs without having to change the cgroups configuration.

Comment: just a note, `cpu.cfs_quota_us` is AFAIK cgroups version 1, now for version 2 same effect is via `cpu.max`